# Interpolating Points using Shapely

Tags: python, python-2.7, shapely

Given a distance in metres (x) and two coordinate pairs in lat/lon format (which form a line segment), I am trying to find a point x meters from point 1 on the line segment between the two points.

I know that in order to use Shapely for this operation, I need to transform the points. Does it make sense to convert the lat/lon pairs to UTM and then use interpolate? If so, will it work to use metres as the measurement for distance, or will I need to convert that to something else as well?

I'm open to suggestions on the best way to go about using Shapely for this.

Comment: this may help you even though its in arcpy https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6724/creating-line-of-varying-distance-from-origin-point-using-python-in-arcgis-deskt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, transform your points to UTM (with pyproj or whatever), make a Shapely `LineString` from them and then call its `interpolate()` method with the distance in meters: https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#object.interpolate.

Answer (score 3):

you can use GeographicLib, check out the examples [here](https://geographiclib.sourceforge.io/1.49/python/examples.html). This answer was inspired by [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/255323/84004) one.

It will get you more accurate values than Cartesian interpolation (using UTM coordinates), and also you won't have to deal with the case of each point (point 1 and point 2) belonging to different UTM zones.